# adding value in nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I am trying to add value to inside dictionary.

```
aDict = { "id" :
             {"name": None },
          "id2" :
             {"foo": None}, 
           ...
         }

for k, v in aDict.items():
     temp = [1,2,3,4]
     aDict[k][v] = temp
```

then I got error, `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`
How can I add value in nested dictionary?

---edit ---
My expected output is,

```
aDict = { "id" :
             {"name": [1,2,3,4] },
          "id2" :
             {"foo": [1,2,3,4] }, 
           ...
         }
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The problem is that `v` here is a `dict`, so by trying to set `aDict[k][v]`, you are setting a key to be a `dict` which isn't allowed

Comment: Are you just looking to always sub in the same value or a more general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do aDict[k], you already got the value which is dict and then you assign the temp to the specific key of the dict.

```
    aDict = { 'id' :
             {'name': None },
             'id2':
             {'foo':None}
            }

for k, v in aDict.items():
    temp = [1,2,3,4]
    for keys in v.keys():
        aDict[k][keys] = temp
```

Output

```
{'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, 'id2': {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}
```

Comment: @jayko03 I have edited the answer. Let me know if it is still incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

For any arbitrary dictionary of dictionaries (no matter how deep it is), this works:

```
def go_deeper(aDict):
    for k, v in aDict.items():
         if v is None:            
             aDict[k] = temp
         else:
             go_deeper(v)
    return aDict
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> temp = [1,2,3,4]     
>>> go_deeper(aDict)
```

For example, for input:

```
aDict = { 'id' :
             {'name': None },
         "id2" :
             {"foo": 
                {'bar': None }
             }
         }
```

the above code returns:

```
{'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, 'id2': {'foo': {'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
temp = [1,2,3,4]
for k in aDict:
    for j in aDict[k]:
        aDict[k][j]=temp
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
{'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, 'id2': {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all keys by using d.keys() then add temp to this dictionary.

```
aDict = { "id" :
             {"name": None },
          "id2" :
             {"foo": None}, 
          "id3" :
             {"bar": None, "boo": None}, 
         }
temp = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for k, v in aDict.items():
    for newKey in v.keys():
        v[newKey] = temp
```

Result:

```
{'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
 'id2': {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
 'id3': {'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'boo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of nested loops. And hence to get your desired output, I would do the following:

```
aDict = { "id" :
             {"name": None },
          "id2" :
             {"foo": None}
         }

for value in aDict.values():
     temp = [1,2,3,4]
     # obtain the key of inner dictionary
     # this line could be written even better, if you're concerned about memory!
     key = list(value.keys())[0]
     # update the inner value
     value[key] = temp
```

When I run this it gives your desired output

```
user@Kareems-MBP:Desktop$ python aDict.py 
{'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, 'id2': {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}}
```

Lastly, the TypeError you were getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` is because you're trying to reference an item in the dictionary **using a dictionary**. Items in a dictionary can be referenced only using their keys. E.g. if we have the following dictionary:

```
myDict = {
'firstname': 'John',
'lastname': 'White'
}
```

and we want to reference the first item, we can do that only using `myDict['firstname']`, we **cannot** do that even with indices `myDict[0]`. You can imagine that you were doing something like this `myDict[{'firstname': 'John'}]`.

I hope this has been helpful!